# How to Debug geth Node that Won't Connect to Parity-based Private Network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I have a private network consisting of two Parity nodes that know about each other from the chainspec file and seem to connect to each other just fine.

I have a third computer.  From here, I can run a Parity node and it will connect to the private network just fine.  But when I run geth on this same computer, it does not connect to the other two parity nodes.

I have initialized this geth with a genesis file that I *think* is appropriate, based on the Parity chain spec file that is working on the Parity nodes.  I say "think" because I see no documentation about this and another question on SE didn't get an answer so I'm just making guesses.

And of course we know the machine and its firewalls aren't the problem because when I run a Parity node from the machine, as I said it connects fine.

The frustrating part is that the geth node doesn't realize that it's not connecting becuase it doesn't know there's anything to connect to.  So I have no errors to start debugging from.  I have tried manually adding peers at the json console.  I get "true" but then listing peers shows nothing.

Can anyone tell me how to start debugging?

Comment: Are you using the same genesis file that the first node was built with? Can you please try that?

Comment: @AshishSinha I think you're mis-reading.  The first node is a Parity node, meaning that it has a chian spec but not a genesis file.  The node that doesn't connect is a geth node.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer your question without seeing the chain spec, but for reference I can provide you with a [working chainspec for both clients](https://github.com/5chdn/crossclient-chainspec):

```
git clone https://github.com/5chdn/crossclient-chainspec
cd crossclient-chainspec
```

Geth:

```
$ geth init --datadir ~/.ethereum/crossclient geth.json
$ geth --datadir ~/.ethereum/crossclient --networkid 1337 --port 31333 --rpcport 8538
```

Parity:

```
$ parity --chain parity.json --port 31337 --jsonrpc-port 8539
```

Or use [keorn's chain spec converter](https://github.com/keorn/parity-spec).

Comment: I"m not sure how the chain spec converter can help, since that seems to convert *to* chain spec file *from* genesis, and I'm going the other way around.  Also I have looked at your files and they appear to carryover the same information that I have carried over in mine.  And I am invoking geth and parity the same way as you are.  What I really need is a way to start debugging, which is what my question is asking for (plus I edited the title to make that even more clear.)

Comment: I went through this debugging process multiple times. It's generally easier to just use working specs. If you wont share your specs, I have no idea how we can help here.

Comment: (A) I don't see anywhere that you went through debugging steps.  Maybe I missed something?  (B) if you don't know how you can help, please stop replying.

Comment: did you mean to specify port 31337 for parity and 31333 for geth?  I'm guessing it's just a simple typo but want to make sure.

Comment: The ports were chosen randomly to avoid conflicts on local machines. If you really want to go through the hassle and debug this issue (instead of using working configurations), increase the verbosity of both clients to the maximum and read through the logs.

Comment: So that suggests that your config for parity and config for geth were not meant to work on the same network.  Or am I misunderstanding?  I thought the ports had to be the same in order for them to discover each other.

Comment: I have tried your files and I get the same error.  But then again, I am not clear on your answer to the question about ports, so perhaps I am not using them correctly.  (I have tried both on port 31337 though, and I get the same error.)  Of course I have tried verbose logging, but that was a while ago and maybe I've learned enough since then to try again.  Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Port numbers doesn't matter, they can connect to any port. Please share the exact error message.

Comment: As I've been saying, there is no error message.  That's why I'm asking for information on how to debug.  There is no error message.  The nodes simply do not recognize each other.

Comment: Run geth with `--verbosity 9` and parity with `-lsync,network=trace` and see if there is anything in the logs.

Comment: Thank you.  That is helpful but actually I did that and posted a question about that output several weeks ago.  Basically the output at level 6+ is too fast to make sense of.  But at level 5, I get "Ethereum peer connected"  "Ethereum handshake failed" and then "Removing p2p peer" many many times.  But that's ok I guess, since none of those are the peers that I *should* be connecting to.  Anyway at the moment, my Parity peers aren't connecting.  I ran a test with your files (same result, incidentally) and now it's taking me a while to get back to my original config.

Comment: Okay, I've got my Parity nodes up again (I still can't figure out why .parity/* and why .local/share/io.... but anyway that's over.)  I'm back to where I was a few weeks ago, using verbosity=4.  Anything more than that is just a flood of IP addresses.  But what I need is a way to debug.  An actual troubleshooting procedure to determine why a node isn't connecting to another.  Like if this was a network connection, you'd check link light first, etc....

Comment: Yeah, verbose mode isn't helping.  It's what I had tried weeks ago when I first had this problem.  I really need debugging steps.  Which is why this post is specifically asking for that.